# Typescript same derived type but all optional keys

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to automatically derive this interface:

```
interface OverrideParamType {
  foo?: FooType
  bar?: BarType
}
```

from this one

```
interface ParamType {
  foo: FooType
  bar: BarType
}
```

The use is in functions ending with:

```
return Object.assign ( {}, baseParams, overrideParams )
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Since typescript 2.1 you can do:

```
interface ParamType {
    foo: FooType
    bar: BarType
}

type PartialParamType = Partial<ParamType>;
```

The definition of `Partial` is:

```
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
};
```

More on that in: [Mapped Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#mapped-types)

[An example in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20FooType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20BarType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20string%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Ainterface%20ParamType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20foo%3A%20FooType%3B%0A%20%20%20%20bar%3A%20BarType%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20PartialParamType%20%3D%20Partial%3CParamType%3E%3B%0A%0Afunction%20normalize(param%3A%20PartialParamType)%3A%20ParamType%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Object.assign(%7B%7D%2C%20param%2C%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%7B%20foo%3A%20%22foo%22%20%7D%2C%20bar%3A%20%7B%20bar%3A%20%22bar%20%22%7D%7D)%3B%0A%7D).

Note that there's no need to define the `Partial` type yourself, it's part of the [lib.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.d.ts#L1381).

Comment: Awesome feature !